# "Internal processing. Please retry to later" What does that mean?

Tags: t-mobile-g2x

Yes, I know what I put was grammatically incorrect. That's exactly how it shows up on my screen.  When I hang up with someone from time to time, the green phone icon in the notification bar does not go away. If I do not immediately turn off my phone and turn it back on, I will be not be able to dial out or receive calls. If the green phone icon is in the notification bar after I hang up with someone, it will give me a message that says, "Internal processing. Please retry to later"

Has anyone heard of this before or know of any possible solutions? I have an LG G2X, which I absolutely regret buying, and before I try to get it replaced, I just wanted to see if there was any way I can fix this.

Thanks!
Kevin